# Is it possible to use lqmm with a mira object?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-mice, quantile-regression

I am using the package `lqmm`, to run a linear quantile mixed model on an imputed object of class `mira` from the package mice.  I tried to make a reproducible example:

```
library(lqmm)
library(mice)
summary(airquality)
imputed<-mice(airquality,m=5)
summary(imputed)
fit1<-lqmm(Ozone~Solar.R+Wind+Temp+Day,random=~1,
           tau=0.5, group= Month, data=airquality,na.action=na.omit)
fit1
summary(fit1)
fit2<-with(imputed, lqmm(Ozone~Solar.R+Wind+Temp+Day,random=~1,
                    tau=0.5, group= Month, na.action=na.omit))
```

```
"Error in lqmm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + Day, random = ~1, tau = 0.5,  : 
  `data' must be a data frame"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get `lqmm()` to work in `mice`. Viewing the code for `lqmm()`, it turns out that it's a picky function. It requires that the `data` argument is supplied, and although it appears to check if the data exists in another environment, it doesn't seem to work in this context. Fortunately, all we have to do to get this to work is capture the data supplied from `mice` and give it to `lqmm()`.

```r
fit2 <- with(imputed, 
             lqmm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + Day,
                  data = data.frame(mget(ls())),
                  random = ~1, tau = 0.5, group = Month, na.action = na.omit))
```

The explanation is that `ls()` gets the names of the variables available, `mget()` gets those variables as a list, and `data.frame()` converts them into a data frame.

---

The next problem you're going to find is that `mice::pool()` requires there to be `tidy()` and `glance()` methods to properly pool the multiple imputations. It looks like neither `broom` nor `broom.mixed` have those defined for `lqmm`. I threw together a very quick and dirty implementation, which you could use if you can't find anything else.
To get `pool(fit2)` to run you'll need to create the function `tidy.lqmm()` as below. Then `pool()` will assume the sample size is infinite and perform the calculations accordingly. You can also create the `glance.lqmm()` function before running `pool(fit2)`, which will tell `pool()` the residual degrees of freedom. Afterwards you can use `summary(pooled)` to find the p-values.

```r
tidy.lqmm <- function(x, conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) {
  broom:::as_tidy_tibble(data.frame(
    estimate = coef(x),
    std.error = sqrt(
      diag(summary(x, covariance = TRUE, 
                   R = 50)$Cov[names(coef(x)),
                               names(coef(x))]))))
}
glance.lqmm <- function(x, ...) {
  broom:::as_glance_tibble(
    logLik = as.numeric(stats::logLik(x)),
    df.residual = summary(x, R = 2)$rdf,
    nobs = stats::nobs(x),
    na_types = "rii")
}
```

Note: `lqmm` uses bootstrapping to estimate the standard error. By default it uses `R = 50` bootstrapping replicates, which I've copied in the `tidy.lqmm()` function. You can change that line to increase the number of replicates if you like.

**WARNING: Use these functions and the results with caution.** I know just enough to be dangerous. To me it looks like these functions work to give sensible results, but there are probably intricacies that I'm not aware of. If you can find a more authoritative source for similar functions that work, or someone who is familiar with `lqmm` or pooling mixed models, I'd trust them more than me.

Comment: do you mind if I steal this as a starting point for `broom.mixed` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Go right ahead, I just adapted them out of `tidy.glm()` and `glance.glm()` myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it did work, however, when I try to pool my results it takes forever.. could it be because my model has 166,000 observations and 94 variables?

Comment: @DeLaCruz I think it is because of how much data there is. Because `summary()` uses bootstrapping to estimate the standard error it needs to re-calculate the model many times. I added `R = 2` to the glance method which should improve the speed with no downside, but I'm not sure how much it will help. If it's insufferably slow you can reduce `R = 50` in the tidy method. That will also reduce the accuracy of the standard error calculations. I don't know enough to say how large an effect it will have.